# Hide certain files/folders from "All My Files"

Tags: macos, finder

How can I hide certain files or folders from "All my files" I'm developing a website with 100s of icons and now they making this section in finder quite redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this this morning on Mac OS X Hints.com:

[10.7: Customize All My Files](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20110921062647996)

I agree that in the case of pros, this All my files thing is quite useless because there is way too many files. This is more a consumer-level thing.